# How to capture image from camera including the overlay Widgets?

Tags: android, flutter

I have created a camera handler using `camera` package. The result is looks like this:

[image]

I want the overlays like the clock and the user profile except the capture and back button to be included in the captured image, is it possible to do this?

Or maybe instead of using capture function, should I use screenshot with condition?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is my `camera.dart` looks like:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

class CameraPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int cameraIdx;
  CameraPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.cameraIdx,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraPageState createState() => _CameraPageState();
}

class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {
  CameraController controller;
  List cameras;
  int selectedCameraIdx;
  String imagePath;
  String _timeString;
  Timer _timer;

  void _getTime() {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final String formattedDateTime = _formatDateTime(now);
    setState(() {
      _timeString = formattedDateTime;
    });
  }

  String _formatDateTime(DateTime dateTime) =>
      DateFormat('HH:mm:ss').format(dateTime);

  String timestamp() => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

// Initialize camera controller
  Future _initCameraController(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }

    // set controller by the camera description with high resolution preset
    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

    // If the controller is updated then update the UI.
    controller.addListener(() {
      // when this widget is mounted clear the state
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }

      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        print('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    // 6
    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  Future<String> takePicture() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return null;
    }
    final Directory extDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/flutter_test';
    await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

    if (controller.value.isTakingPicture) {
      // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await controller.takePicture(filePath);
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }

  void logError(String code, String message) =>
      print('Error: $code\nError Message: $message');

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
  }

  void onCaptureButtonPressed() {
    takePicture().then((String filePath) {
      print(filePath);
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          imagePath = filePath;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Check if camera available
    availableCameras().then((availableCameras) {
      cameras = availableCameras;
      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        setState(() {
          // Select front camera as default
          if (widget.cameraIdx != null) {
            selectedCameraIdx = widget.cameraIdx;
          } else {
            selectedCameraIdx = 1;
          }
        });

        _initCameraController(cameras[selectedCameraIdx]).then((void v) {});
      } else {
        print("No camera available");
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      // Print error if any
      print('Error: $err.code\nError Message: $err.message');
    });

    _timeString = _formatDateTime(DateTime.now());
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => _getTime());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;

    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Transform.scale(
            scale: controller.value.aspectRatio / deviceRatio,
            child: Center(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: CameraPreview(controller),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 110.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, right: 0.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.arrowLeft,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, right: 10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('Donny Pratama',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 16.0)),
                              Text(
                                'Front End Developer',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 30.0,
                          backgroundImage:
                              NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/150'),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 180.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          _timeString,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 50.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                              child: Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.mapMarkerAlt,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 12.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Yogyakarta, Indonesia',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 120.0,
              // color: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 60.0,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        elevation: 0.5,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.camera),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: onCaptureButtonPressed,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Donny, did you get any solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately, not yet.. still searching for clues..